# Storing Arrays in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I tried to store arrays in an array of objects, but the problem is that the value of the arrays in each object becomes the same. For example, in the code below, xA3[0].y would be the same as xA3[1].y, which are supposed to be different.

```
for (var m1 = 0; m1 < selectedTemp.length; m1++){


        for (i=0; i<=2; i+=xStep) {
            xShear[xIndex] = 10**i;
            xVis[xIndex] = rand(0, 25)/(i == 0 ? 1:i);

            xIndex++;

        };
        xIndex=0;
        xAx.push(xShear);
        xAy.push(xVis);
        for (var xi=0; xi<=2; xi+=xStep) {

            console.log(selectedTemp[m1] + " --- xAy --- " + xIndex + " : " + xAy[m1][xIndex]);
            xIndex++;
        };  
        xIndex=0;

    };  
    xIndex=0;
    for (var m2 = 0; m2 < selectedTemp.length; m2++ ){
        xA3.push({
            x : xAx[m2],
            y : xAy[m2],

        });
        for (var xi=0; xi<=2; xi+=xStep) {

            console.log(selectedTemp[m2] + " *** xAy *** " + xIndex + " : " + m2+ " : " + xAy[m2][xIndex]);
            xIndex++;
        };  
        xIndex=0;
    };
}
```

Comment: please add the missing data as well.

Comment: Add `xShear = []; xVis = [];` before `for (i=0; i<=2; i+=xStep)` loop.

Comment: For all x of xAx (same holds for y) you are pushing the same array xShear.
you should put xShear for el 0, and a copy xShear.slice(0) for the other elements (assuming you don't want a reference to the same array but different arrays having the same content). Proposal of ponury-kostek adresses the problem of reference as well

Answer (score 0):

Please declare all variables and `'use strict'` mode to prevent global variables and initialize the variables at least at the reusing of the same variables. Otherwise you get the same object refrence thi same values for all same refrerences.

```js
'use strict';
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var selectedTemp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    xShear,
    xVis,
    xIndex = 0,
    m1, m2, i, xi,
    xAx = [],
    xAy = [],
    xA3 = [],
    xStep = 1;

for (var m1 = 0; m1 < selectedTemp.length; m1++) {
  xShear = [];
  xVis = []
  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i += xStep) {
    xShear[xIndex] = 10 ** i;
    xVis[xIndex] = rand(0, 25) / (i || 1);
    xIndex++;
  }
  xIndex = 0;
  xAx.push(xShear);
  xAy.push(xVis);
  for (var xi = 0; xi <= 2; xi += xStep) {
    console.log(selectedTemp[m1] + " --- xAy --- " + xIndex + " : " + xAy[m1][xIndex]);
    xIndex++;
  }
  xIndex = 0;
}
xIndex = 0;
for (var m2 = 0; m2 < selectedTemp.length; m2++) {
  xA3.push({ x: xAx[m2], y: xAy[m2] });
  for (var xi = 0; xi <= 2; xi += xStep) {
    console.log(selectedTemp[m2] + " *** xAy *** " + xIndex + " : " + m2 + " : " + xAy[m2][xIndex]);
    xIndex++;
  }
  xIndex = 0;
}
console.log(xA3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ain't it a bit sad to reinitialize ```xShear``` and ```xVis``` for all ```selectedTemp```?